# Impementing Authorize.Net CIM for guest customer, are these basically one-time use only

Tags: payflowpro, authorize.net-cim

When implementing Authorize.Net CIM for guests (unregistered) and customers who choose NOT to save their credit cards, but where we still require the CIM feature of being able to refer to the credit card information for later processing (pre-orders, backorders, drop-ship orders)...

Does this imply that the CIM profile created for those customer types will be pretty much one-time use only?  One CIM Profile ID per credit card transaction, in other words.

If I understand correctly, the CIM Profile IDs won't expire.  Wouldn't that potentially generate way too many one-time use Profile IDs?

According to other posts Authorize.Net CIM doesn't really have a Reference Transaction concept like [PayFlow Pro Reference Transaction for Authorize.Net CIM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24386643/performing-transaction-based-on-previous-transactions-in-authorize-net-cim), and that using the CIM profile is the solution.